# Django filter on many to many with having count

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many, psql, having

After a lot of try, I am not able to translate this kind of sql queries into django filtering.
Basically, it is retrieving all users with at least x selected tags (and other filters).
In the case of two tags, users need to have both tags, I don't want to retrieve users with at least one of the tag.

Here are my definitions:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

SQL query will look like:

```sql
SELECT user.id
FROM user
INNER JOIN "user_tags" ON ("user"."id" = "user_tags"."user_id")
AND "user_tags"."tag_id" in (8, 163) group by "user"."id", user_tags.user_id having count(*) = 2
ORDER BY user.id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

As you can see, the `having count(*)` part is done on the created m2m table `user_tags`, and the filtering of tags also `"user_tags"."tag_id" in (8, 163)`

Is it achievable in a django way?
All my attempts use `user` and `tab` tables, never the created table.

Thanks,

EDIT: passing @preeti-y as right answer as it looks like this is the way to go.
But for my specific case and for performances reasons, I directly used a `RawSQL` method allowing me to correctly pass it with other filters.

```py
Q(id__in=RawSQL(
                    '''SELECT U0.id FROM "user" U0 
                    INNER JOIN "user_tags" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."user_id") 
                    WHERE U1."tag_id" IN %s
                    GROUP BY U0."id" 
                    HAVING COUNT(U1."user_id") = %s''', (tuple(value), len(value),)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your query, in Django way, you can do `Count()` with `filter` argument in the annotation like this:

```py
User.objects.annotate(
  matched_tag_count=Count('tags', filter=Q(tags__in=[8, 163]))
).filter(matched_tag_count=2)
```

Comment: This works, but performances are terrible with others filters.
I used a RawSQL in the end...